# Cannot write to local shared directory

Tags: windows, network-share, file-permissions

I wondered if anyone has experienced this issue...

We noticed a permissions error on a server that uses a case management system. It works by writing to locally hosted shared folders. After a reboot, we get the error - "Destination folder access denied" "You need permission to proform this action" when trying to write to the directory off \Server\Share (as any user account). Also, this seems to happen on any machine in our network - I created a share on a workstation and can view \Workstation\Share - but can't write to the directory.

If I navigate to \IPAddress\Share on host and client - can read and write

If I navigate to \FQDN\Share on host and client - can read and write

If I navigate to \Server\Share on a client as any user - can read and write

Also, mapping the drive on host and client - can read and write

Hoping someone can shed some light on this if they've had similar issues?

I've checked offline file sync is disabled, no credentials are stored in credential manager, clearing the CSC cache, file permissions (set for everyone, full control), DNS, NETBios.

Thanks,

**EDIT**

Also rolled back any Windows updates to a time when this was working.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different locations where permissions have to be configured when creating a Windows shared folder. If you right-click on a folder and select "properties" of that folder the properties dialog opens and you see the "sharing" tab and the "security" tab.

If you select the Security tab you can configure permissions on the files in the shared folder. This is the point where you define who can(and who cannot) access which files.

If you select the Sharing tab you can check the box indicating that you want to share the folder. You would also indicate the name you want to use as the shared folder name. Right below that is a button that people don't seem to notice. It says "permissions".  (Select it, and grant full control to "everyone".) This is the point where you define who has permission to access the share.

OK, so you set access to the share on the sharing tab and you set access to the files on the security tab. The permission denied message implies that you did not set share permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this wasn't the issue. If it was the permissions in the sharing tab - I'd expect to get this error when writing to the share via FQDN and IP address, not just hostname. The issue was NetSupport, uninstalled and rebooted - all working now.